# Prototype design pattern to be used when new is costly, but we do new in clone

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have been learning about the various design patterns. In particular for the Prototype design pattern the use case states that it should be used when calling new is costly. And hence use clone.
But within the clone() function we ultimately end up using the new operator.
Can someone please explain me what is the significance of the use case for this pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you have an object whose constructor performs some kind of expensive process and as such performing the `new` operation on it is rather undesireable, now imagine that you wish to perform seperate operations on the data contained in that object you have a couple of choices: you can wait till one operation is finished then pass a reference to that object to the next operation, or you can `clone()` the object and have both operations performed concurrently.

You cannot avoid using the `new` operator (at least once) as the object has to come into existance some time. However by using a `clone()` member function you avoid having to do it multiple times.

What seems to be left out in many examples of the prototype pattern is that in many implementations these objects are cached (in a hashtable, or map etc) so the first time the object is needed the full expense is incurred, however on all subsequent occaisions it can be cloned with less expense.

The prototype pattern is quite a flexible one and how it looks will very much depend on the needs of a particular system, and in many cases prototype and abstract factory can look pretty similar.

**edit**
Cloning is cheaper than creating a new object as you only need to make a  copy of the data as opposed to calling the expensive operation that gathered/created the data in the first place such as multiple sql queries over a large database or crawling a website for certain tags etc.

Comment: It isn't clearer to me from your answer why cloning an object would be cheaper than constructing it.

Comment: Also, why is it then better to use the prototype pattern this way, with the clone() function, as opposed to using a simple assignment via assignment operator (or overloaded one) - talking about C++? In any case, some constructor will be called anyway, right?